# ph-schematron validation error message

Tags: java, xml, validation, schematron

I'm using [ph-schematron](https://phax.github.io/ph-schematron/) to validate my XML files. I'm able to validate the files correctly but I couldn't find how to generate reports about failing assertions.

This is my context(point-of-interest):

```xml
<bpmn:extensionElements>
    <activiti:in sourceExpression="RESERVATION" target="OPERATION_CODE"/>
    <activiti:in sourceExpression="true" target="IS_SYNC"/>
</bpmn:extensionElements>
```

This is my Schematron schema:

```xml
<iso:schema
    xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"
    xmlns:iso="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"
    queryBinding='xslt2'
    schemaVersion='ISO19757-3'>
    <iso:title>Test ISO schematron file. Introduction mode</iso:title>
    <iso:ns prefix='bpmn' uri='http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL'/>
    <iso:ns prefix='activiti' uri='http://activiti.org/bpmn'/>

    <iso:let name="callActivity" value="bpmn:definitions/bpmn:process/bpmn:callActivity"/>
    <iso:let name="inSourceExpression" value="child::activiti:in/sourceExpression"/>
    <iso:let name="outSourceExpression" value="child::activiti:out/sourceExpression"/>
    <iso:let name="inTarget" value="child::activiti:in/target"/>
    <iso:let name="outTarget" value="child::activiti:out/target"/>

    <!-- Your constraints go here -->
    <iso:pattern id="RESERVATION">
        <iso:p>
        This pattern validates call activities with RESERVATION operation code.
        </iso:p>
        <iso:rule context="$callActivity[bpmn:extensionElements/activiti:in[(@target='OPERATION_CODE') and (@sourceExpression='RESERVATION')]]/bpmn:extensionElements">
            <iso:assert test="count(($inSourceExpression='RESERVATION') and ($inTarget='OPERATION_CODE')) = 0">err1</iso:assert>
            <iso:assert test="count(($inSourceExpression='true') and ($inTarget='IS_SYNC')) = 1">err2</iso:assert>
        </iso:rule>
    </iso:pattern>
</iso:schema>
```

This is my Java code:

```java
public static boolean validateXMLViaPureSchematron(@Nonnull final String aSchematronFilePath, @Nonnull final File aXMLFile) throws Exception {
    final SchematronResourcePure schematronResourcePure = SchematronResourcePure.fromClassPath(aSchematronFilePath);
    IPSErrorHandler errorHandler = new CollectingPSErrorHandler();
    schematronResourcePure.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
    final boolean validSchematron = schematronResourcePure.isValidSchematron();
    if (!validSchematron) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Schematron!");
    }
    final Source streamSource = new StreamSource(aXMLFile);
    final EValidity schematronValidity = schematronResourcePure.getSchematronValidity(streamSource);
    return schematronValidity.isValid();
}
```

I can see the result of the validation by calling `schematronResourcePure.getSchematronValidity(streamSource)` but I want to see (a report would be sufficient) which rules are failed(`err1` or `err2`). I've read about `SVRL` but I don't know how to generate report.
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply call `applySchematronValidationToSVRL` to get the full SVRL (Schematron Validation Result List) document. You can query it for failed asserts or reports.

Code example where only failed asserts are printed:

```
SchematronOutputType schematronOutputType = schematronResourcePure.applySchematronValidationToSVRL(streamSource);
List<Object> failedAsserts = schematronOutputType.getActivePatternAndFiredRuleAndFailedAssert();
for (Object object : failedAsserts) {
    if (object instanceof FailedAssert) {
        FailedAssert failedAssert = (FailedAssert) object;
        System.out.println(failedAssert.getText());
        System.out.println(failedAssert.getTest());
    }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively you can use `SVRLHelper.getAllFailedAssertions (schematronOutputType)` - that returns a list of `SVRLFailedAssert` instead.

Comment: How to get the source XML line number of a FailedAssert?

Comment: @RobertoRusso that is unfortunately not possible. To figure out what element it is, you need to dig deeper into the created SVRL. Check the `active-pattern` and the `fired-rules` elements to get more context.
I suggest you get yourself the SVRL printed as a whole (`new SVRLMarshaller ().getAsString (schematronOutputType)`)  to understand. hth